# How to revoke certificate ".pfx"?

Tags: nginx, ssl, certificate, certificate-revocation

I am using an nginx setup, with a CRL.
However, I do not have access to the certificates I want to revoke. Let's say I only know the CN/Thumbprint/... is that feasible?

If not, I could have a workaround to actually have access to that certificate, however it is a ".pfx" certificate bundle. Can we revoke these?

Comment: PFX is a container format which includes the certificate. Apart from that subject is not enough since it does not uniquely identifies a certificate - there can be multiple certificates with the same subject.

Answer (score 0):

As **Steffen Ullrich** pointed out, PFX is a container format. On Windows you can double click to open/import it. On all supported platforms you can use OpenSSL to export the certificate (public part):

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -in ".\container.pfx" -nokeys -out ".\certificate.pem" -passin "pass:12345678"
```

Now to the revocation... The revocation must be requested from the issuer of the certificate. To read the issuer we can use OpenSSL again:

```sh
openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -noout -issuer
```

Whatever is put out should give you an indication where to request the revocation.

Technically the revocation means that the **issuing CA recognizes a certain certificate as invalid and writes its serial number to a certificate revocation list** (CRL). The CRL, as a certificate has a lifetime. It must be written new from time to time. CRL files are signed with the CA certificate - if you do not have the private key of the CA you cannot revoke a certificate - that is why I said you must *request a revocation*.

For a revocation usually the serial number of a certificate is needed. HEre is how to get it from the *.pem file we just extracted from the *.pfx file:

```sh
openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -noout -serial
```

Now you should know who is the **issuer** of the certificate and can request a revocation for the given *serial number*. If the revocation is done by some REST interface, SOAP, RPC, a web form or even paper trail really depends on the CA, which can be internal of your organization, run by a government or privately held organization offering public services. As long as you do not provide that information we cannot help you any further.

Please feel free to edit your question with updated information, so we can continue working it out.

Comment: I need to revoke the certificate using it's serial number, any clue how that is done?
I have the CRL, and the certificate serial number. 
However no clue on how to add that to the CRL

Comment: I updated the answer and asked for more information to help you